# custom validation on ajax success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to display tool tip message on ajax success, but i am stuck with code but css is working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mobileNumber").blur(function () {
        if ($("#mobileNumber").val().trim() != "") {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/Home/IsMobileNumberExist',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { contactNo: $("#mobileNumber").val().trim() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: setCustomValidity
            });
        }
    });
});

function setCustomValidity(response) {
    var mobileNumber = document.getElementById("mobileNumber");
    if (response) {
        $("#mobileNumber").addClass('invalidValidation');
        mobileNumber.addEventListener("input", function () {
            mobileNumber.setCustomValidity("mobile no exists");
        });
    } else {
        mobileNumber.setCustomValidity("");
    }
}
```

thanks its not working for me actually i want to show a tooltip message with css effect with my textbox on ajax sucess. CSS is working but i am unable to show the tooltip.

Comment: call function with parameter `setCustomValidity(response)`...

Comment: Please refer to my answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add response object coming after the successful ajax....because your  `setCustomValidity()` function expects a parameter. You can pass in a callback function that handles the result:

```
   $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/IsMobileNumberExist',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { contactNo: $("#mobileNumber").val().trim() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){ setCustomValidity(response)}
          });
```

Comment: `success` expects a *function* callback, `setCustomValidity()` does not seem to return one...

Comment: thanks Tushar but its not working for me actually i want to show a tooltip message with css effect with my textbox on ajax sucess. CSS  is working but i am unable to show the tooltip.